# Add Start Up Delay for Concurrency Thread Group in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I am new to Jmeter and I'm looking to simulate a particular scenario. I need to run a set of Concurrency Thread groups, but I have to add a start-up delay for all the threads. (5 sec).

I have a thread group A (basic) which needs to run for the first 2 sec. After this, my set of Concurrency thread groups need to start (so after a startup delay of 3 sec).

I can achieve this through normal thread group, but how can I achieve this through concurrency thread group?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) instead

> "Ultimate" means there will be no need in further Thread Group plugins. The features that everyone needed in JMeter and they finally available:
>
> - infinite number of schedule records
> - separate ramp-up time

And put Initial Delay of 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the delay using the following approach

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to be the first Sampler in your Concurrency Thread Group.
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   if (vars.get('delay') == null) {
       Thread.sleep(3000)
       vars.put('delay', 'f')
   }
   ```
3. Add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of the JSR223 Sampler and make "Number of Simulated Users to Group by" equal to the desired concurrency

All threads will "meet" at the JSR223 Sampler, wait for 3 seconds and then start executing your other samplers.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I tried this way but unfortunately none of the subsequent threads are getting started

Comment: I cannot help without seeing your Concurrency Thread Group and Synchronizing Timer configurations. Contents of *jmeter.log* file can also shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I'm trying to test an application where I need to do a Sign On call (API) initially and get a session token. And this session token i need to use in all my threads as Authentication header (HTTP).   So I need to run only my Sign on call (normal thread) initially and get the token using Regex extractor. (This is done!). I need my other threads (concurreny threads) to start only after my normal thread